# Getting data Id in javascript in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have below HTML

```
<template>
    <section data-id="click-id" onclick={handleOnClick}>
        section
        <div>
            div1
        </div>
        <div>
            div2
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  handleOnClick(event) {
    alert('dataId is '+event.target.dataset.id)
  }
}
```

if I click on the section then I get the data-id value but if I click on the div1 or div2 I don't get the id used on the section tag

one option is sto assign the same id to the child div 2nd one is to query the parent dom element in the javascript, can someone please confirm if is there any other 3rd option available?

below is the playground code also

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/PlVYAzWWyiAeb5ibG4mH/src/app.js?p=stories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget.dataset.id`